# What does this sentence about Dvořáks 9. Sinfonie mean?

Tags: meaning

> Mit der 9. Sinfonie op. 95 „Aus der Neuen Welt“, die Dvořák bereits im Mai 1893 in New York vollendet hatte, verbindet das Quartett der „amerikanische“ Einschlag der Gedanken  und die sehr klare, plastische und verhältnismäßig einfache formale Anordnung.

I'm not even sure what the subject is. Normally I expect Subject+ verbindet + akusativ + mit etwas. What links what and what in this sentence ?

Comment: Ein Link zur Quelle wäre hilfreich. Bin 3x über das *der* gestolpert, weil ich da ein *den amerikanischen Einschlag* lesen wollte, als Quartett 4 Musiker, nicht ein anderes Musikstück vor Augen.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/12._Streichquartett_(Dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k), der dritte Absatz :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence is in bad style and has a misleading structure. The structure is as follows:

> Mit [der 9 Sinfonie]<sub>1</sub> ... verbindet [das Quartett]<sub>2</sub> [der "amerikanische" Einschlag ... und die einfache ... Anordnung]<sub>3</sub>.

while 3 is the subject [!] in Nominativ, 1 is the Dativ-object which is demanded by the verb "verbinden *mit*" and 2 is the Akkusativ-object demanded by "verbinden". The word-order might suggest that 3 was an object, but this is misleading and the sentence is inapprehensible for germans as well.

So the meaning of the sentence is aproximately

*The 9<sup>th</sup> sinfony "from the New World" (which Dvořák already had finished in May 1983 in New York) and the quartet share the "american" style of motives and the very clear, plastic and relatively simple formal order.*

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This sentence was taken from wikipedia, I expect every sentence there to be written in the most rigorous german. I was mistaken :P

Comment: I like it how you used the words *very clear, plastic and relatively simple formal order.* to translate this horrifying monster of a sentence.

Comment: @Janka Yeah, maybe the WP-author was making a rather advanced joke in contradicting the content of the sentence - simplicity of formal forder - with their own language describing this simplicity.